# Close all child levels of a navigation when parent is closing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on a menu where I want to close all sub navigations when clicking on another link with a sub navigation, it currently only collapses the sub navigation on the same level but not the deeper ones.

**Example:**

- Click on A1 > A2A > A3A > A4A
- Then click on B1
- Click on A1 again
- You see that A2A, A3A and A4A are still completely unfolded

```js
$('li.has-children').click(function() {
  
 $(this).children('.wrap').addClass('active');
 
 $(this).closest('ul').children('li').not(this).children('.wrap').removeClass('active');
 
});
```

```css
ul,
ul li { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

.wrap {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.has-children-level1 {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has-children has-children-level1">
    <a class="">link A1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link A2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link A3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link A4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link A2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link A3B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link A4B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children has-children-level1">
    <a class="">link B1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link B2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link B3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link B4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link B2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link B3B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link B4B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have added the working answer, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified your logic to check if the parent level is clicked, remove the active class from all the child elements.

```
if($(this).hasClass('has-children')){
  $(this).siblings().find('*').removeClass('active')
}
```

Also, I have added `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent `bubbling` of the click event

---

<kbd>**Working Code below**</kbd>

```js
$('li.has-children').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('.wrap').addClass('active');


  if ($(this).hasClass('has-children')) {
    $(this).siblings().find('*').removeClass('active')
  }


});
```

```css
ul,
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.wrap {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.has-children-level1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has-children has-children-level1">
    <a class="">link A1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link A2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link A3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link A4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link A2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link A3B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link A4B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children has-children-level1">
    <a class="">link B1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link B2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link B3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link B4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link B2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link B3B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link B4B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is getting close but the problem is now that if you click on A2A and then on A2B, A3A is not closing anymore

Comment: This was almost it, I changed 'has-children-level1' to 'has-children' and now it works, if you can change that in your answer than I can accept it :)

Comment: Yep done, thanks for pointing out

Answer (score -1):

before setiing the active one reomve all the other active.

```js
$('li.has-children').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  var p = $this.parents('.has-children');

  $('div.wrap').not(this).removeClass('active')

  if(p.length){
  $(`.wrap`,p).not($this.find('.wrap .wrap')).addClass('active')
  }
  else{
    $this.children('.wrap').addClass('active');
  }
  return false
 
});
```

```css
ul,
ul li { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

.wrap {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.has-children-level1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has-children has-children-level1">
    <a class="">link A1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link A2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link A3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link A4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link A2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link A3B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link A4B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children has-children-level1">
    <a class="">link B1</a>
    <div class="wrap wrap-0">
      <ul>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link B2A</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link B3A</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link B4A</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="has-children has-children-level2">
          <a class="">link B2B</a>
          <div class="wrap wrap-1">
            <ul>
              <li class="has-children has-children-level3">
                <a class="">link B3B</a>
                <div class="wrap wrap-2">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="has-children has-children-level4">
                      <a class="">link B4B</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this unfortunately breaks the other sub levels from opening

Comment: i have edited the code